# How to move all data in columns into a single column (not merging) and then split into new columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, format

I have created a data nightmare using Excel to do our project data entry. I have two spreadsheets with a total of 20 tabs. The data structure is identical in each tab. I have managed to create a CSV file with the data from one of the tabs in one of the spreadsheets merged into a structure I hope can then be imported into a R dataframe and then re-structured into a meaningful format.

Each tab has approximately 120 columns (depending on the number of sampling dates) and 100 rows (depends on the number of species observed). Each row is a species of plant and each column contains the data for a specific date and specific location.

I would like to convert my (sample data) five by five (rows and columns) dataframe into a single column with 25 rows.

Then I would like to take the data from each row (record, for example: "08/10/2017,2 to 3,Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris,V,vt") and convert it into the following columns:

Date, Segment, Species, Code 1, Code 2, ...

Each observation on a date at a segment for a species contains between 1 and 7 different codes, so the number of columns for each record will generate between 4 and 10 columns. Note the result will follow the above structure. Each observation is enclosed in quotes and the data is delimited with commas.

Thank you for your help!

```
test <- structure(list(V120 = c("03/10/2017,3 to 4,Salix phylicifolia,Y", 
"03/10/2017,3 to 4,Saussurea alpina,Y", "03/10/2017,3 to 4,Silene dioica,Y", 
"03/10/2017,3 to 4,Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris,Y", "03/10/2017,3 to 4,Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata,Y"), V121 = c("03/10/2017,4 to 5,Salix phylicifolia,C,0,g1,L3", "03/10/2017,4 to 5,Saussurea alpina,Y", "03/10/2017,4 to 5,Silene dioica,Y", "03/10/2017,4 to 5,Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris,Y", "03/10/2017,4 to 5,Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata,Y"), V122 = c("08/10/2017,1 to 2,Salix phylicifolia,Vb,L4", "08/10/2017,1 to 2,Saussurea alpina,uf,V,vt", "08/10/2017,1 to 2,Silene dioica,Vb,vt", "08/10/2017,1 to 2,Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris,V,vt", "08/10/2017,1 to 2,Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata,L4"), V123 = c("08/10/2017,2 to 3,Salix phylicifolia,L4", "08/10/2017,2 to 3,Saussurea alpina,uf,V,vt", "08/10/2017,2 to 3,Silene dioica,vt", "08/10/2017,2 to 3,Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris,V,vt", "08/10/2017,2 to 3,Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata,Y"), V124 = c("08/10/2017,3 to 4,Salix phylicifolia,Y", "08/10/2017,3 to 4,Saussurea alpina,Y", "08/10/2017,3 to 4,Silene dioica,Y", "08/10/2017,3 to 4,Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris,Y", "08/10/2017,3 to 4,Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata,Y")), .Names = c("V120", "V121", "V122", "V123", "V124"), row.names = 41:45, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nightmare? Excel users should use that word more often, upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, along with `stack` from base R:

```
library(splitstackshape)
head(cSplit(stack(test), "values", ","))
#     ind   values_1 values_2                          values_3 values_4 values_5 values_6 values_7
# 1: V120 03/10/2017   3 to 4                Salix phylicifolia        Y       NA       NA       NA
# 2: V120 03/10/2017   3 to 4                  Saussurea alpina        Y       NA       NA       NA
# 3: V120 03/10/2017   3 to 4                     Silene dioica        Y       NA       NA       NA
# 4: V120 03/10/2017   3 to 4 Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris        Y       NA       NA       NA
# 5: V120 03/10/2017   3 to 4    Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata        Y       NA       NA       NA
# 6: V121 03/10/2017   4 to 5                Salix phylicifolia        C        0       g1       L3
```

Or you can use straight "data.table", like this:

```
library(data.table)
head(setDT(test)[, list(var = unlist(.SD))][, tstrsplit(var, ",")])
#            V1     V2                                V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# 1: 03/10/2017 3 to 4                Salix phylicifolia  Y NA NA NA
# 2: 03/10/2017 3 to 4                  Saussurea alpina  Y NA NA NA
# 3: 03/10/2017 3 to 4                     Silene dioica  Y NA NA NA
# 4: 03/10/2017 3 to 4 Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris  Y NA NA NA
# 5: 03/10/2017 3 to 4    Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata  Y NA NA NA
# 6: 03/10/2017 4 to 5                Salix phylicifolia  C  0 g1 L3
```

If you prefer the "tidyverse", you can try something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
  gather(var, val, everything()) %>%
  separate(val, into = c("Date", "Segment", "Species", paste("Code", 1:7, sep = "_")), sep = ",") %>%
  head()
#    var       Date Segment                           Species Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 Code_5
# 1 V120 03/10/2017  3 to 4                Salix phylicifolia      Y   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 2 V120 03/10/2017  3 to 4                  Saussurea alpina      Y   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 3 V120 03/10/2017  3 to 4                     Silene dioica      Y   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 4 V120 03/10/2017  3 to 4 Solidago virgaurea ssp. alpestris      Y   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 5 V120 03/10/2017  3 to 4    Sorbus aucuparia ssp. glabrata      Y   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 6 V121 03/10/2017  4 to 5                Salix phylicifolia      C      0     g1     L3   <NA>
#   Code_6 Code_7
# 1   <NA>   <NA>
# 2   <NA>   <NA>
# 3   <NA>   <NA>
# 4   <NA>   <NA>
# 5   <NA>   <NA>
# 6   <NA>   <NA>
```

The "tidyverse" solution depends on you knowing how many columns you'll have in the end, which in your case you know.

Obviously, remove `head()` from any of these options with your actual data...

Comment: your 'data.table' solution is elegant and easy! This made my Excel nightmare bearable. Thank you!